# How to replicate facebook photo view and show photos very fast from web

Tags: iphone, view

I have to create same functionality as facebook has does like all the photos display at one view and from that user can choose photo and it goes to large photo. This photos are showing very fast. I have 5 photos from web but it take so much time. Does anyone know how they shows photo very fast.

Comment: It seems like you're asking us to optimize code you never gave :D. Make it clear how you're currently pulling photos from the web.

Comment: Please split your secondary question into another posting.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the answer but I suggest you look at the [three20 source code on github](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master). Joe Hewitt (who wrote the Facebook app) published much of its code including the photo view. There is also [a Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/) that discusses three20.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the iphone app in particular, but I do know that the main facebook website prefetches images in photo albums.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook creates multiple sizes of each photo when it is uploaded. They also convert all the photos to png I'm pretty sure, likely reducing the file size of the original photo. I know creative has often complained about the "quality" of photos after uploaded to Facebook.

This allows them to deliver the appropriate sized image (both dimensions and file size) for quick display rather than delivering a full sized image and having the client resize it.