# Which view should i use to display large photos from a TabBar application

Tags: iphone, view, uitabview

Hi i have used Tab Bar Application with 4 tabs and i have set navigation controller from IB.

Now for my [photo view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005420/how-facebook-iphone-app-shows-photos-very-fast-from-web), when user choose photo from list, it should display large photo. For larger photo, which view should i use?. If i will self.view and it will display both tab bar and navigation bar. If i will give tabbarcontroller..view then navigation controller is not displayed. I need navigation controller when user tap on image.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a fine beginner question.

Comment: Could be because it is an exact duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005420/how-facebook-iphone-app-shows-photos-very-fast-from-web

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tab bar to disappear when the user taps on an image, you should probably base the interface on a subclassed UINavigationController and insert a tab bar (without controller) manually. You'll have to handle events from the tab bar in your UINavigationController subclass. When the user taps an image, you can simply set it in a UIImageView controlled by a separate UIViewController and push that controller on the nagigation controller's stack.

(There are tutorials on-line on how to combine a navigation and tab bar interface. You might find other ways of doing what you need).